# How to solve AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ABC'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, frida

I am a bit new to Linux but I am having an issue with my recently installed package `Frida`. It worked fine until yesterday when I installed `fridump` as well.

When I try to use `Frida` I am getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/frida", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/frida_tools/repl.py", line 34, in main
    from frida_tools import _repl_magic
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/frida_tools/_repl_magic.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Magic(abc.ABC):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ABC'
```

I have Python 3.9.10 installed but I guess it has to do with Python 2.7 and `Frida` using new version but I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Python2 is no longer supported. I would check if you can uninstall it as this will prevent a number of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I got no experience for both tools but after a bit search ,
My suggestion is to uninstall (remove) fridump and Farida,

```
pip uninstall <packagename>
```

in your case   `frida` is the package name

And use different virtual environment for each tool :

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3env
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python py2env
```

to know more about virtual environments [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

So each environment can work fine separately without version conflicts and later on will help install any additional needed tools for each package.

Comment: Why `python3.3` instead of just `python3`? Python 3.3 is a bit old (I think the oldest still supported version is 3.6) and will not work on most Linux systems unless they have created soft links to the recent Python 3 version.

Comment: nah , i wasn't mean a specific version , sorry , i meant any 3.x just to differentiate between it and python2 , i edited it , thanks for the question

Comment: But you are using it in a command, so the people reading your answer will try to use it exactly as it is written. Just make it `python3` so it is clear and works universally.

Comment: okay , thanks for the clarification and i did so , hope it solves his issue and marked the question as answered